# связать несколько разных inputs в angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть массив значений колонок

```
columns= [
  { name: 'Name', filter: { type: 'text' }},
  { name: 'Age', filter: { type: 'text' }}
]
```

затем вывожу в html шаблоне следующее
<input *ngIf="columns.filter.type === 'text'" type={columns.filter.type}>

Как мне связать данные в инпутаx, и как отслеживать(input, checkbox, select ...)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какая связь должна быть между инпутами, добавьте больше кода и и описание того, что есть сейчас и что нужно получить в итоге

Answer (score 0):

Используй [реактивные формы Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), затем подписывайся на форму инпута, который тебе нужен и отслеживай актуальное значение.